# Cross-platform implementation of incremental loading

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, printer-control-language

Currently I'm porting my UWP app to reference a cross-platform PCL that consists all the logic.
While this works great, I am struggling with platform-specific implementations like the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface on the UWP platform.

The problem is that the PCL contains a ViewModel (called `MainViewModel`). This ViewModel has a property called `Items` which is basically an `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>`.
The ListView control of the UWP platform does support incremental loading, if the underlying collection implements the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface.

What is the best approach to implement this interface while keeping as much as possible of the shared logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if that's not a real solution, my approach was to kick the incremental loading logic out of the PCL, so that the MainViewModel.Items property contained all the items.
I've then created a new UWP MainViewModel which then handles the incremental loading logic using the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` Interface.

Comment: I used a similar approach in the past, worked really well! :)